# how to prevent system font-size changing effects to android application?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I recently finished developing my android application. I used sp (Scaled pixels) for all textSize. The problem is when i adjusted the system font-size, my application's font-sizes are changing. I can use dp (Device independent pixels) but it will take too long to maintain my application.

I referenced text size from [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textSize).

Is there a way to prevent system font-size changing effects to my application ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you require your text to remain the same size, you'll have to use `dp`.

To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP):

> An `sp` is the same base unit, but is scaled by the **user's preferred text size** (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Emphasis mine.

So you're seeing the expected behaviour for using `sp` as your units for text size.

I don't understand what you mean about using dp taking too long to maintain your app - as far as I can tell, it'll exactly be the same amount of effort? (perhaps less, though it'll likely make it less usable for users with poor eyesight)

Comment: I agreed your explaination. But in IOS it restricted to specific applications like calendar, mails, ect by the System. For Android, there is not restriction. So can i prevent my application from changing system font-szie.

Comment: You cannot stop the user from changing the system font size; you'll just have to use `dp` and ignore the lint errors! There's a [blog post on how to disable lint errors](http://tools.android.com/recent/ignoringlintwarnings) which might be useful.

Comment: While your usage may be very specific and require a constant font size, I'd recommend considering how you can accommodate varying font sizes in your layouts, rather than just avoiding it altogether. It'll make for a much better experience for your users.

Comment: If you have a working app, switching all `sp` values to `dp` values is error prone and requires more time to do so. Then if chose to switch back to support it again, you need to revert all these changes. It just makes more sense to override `fontScale` in a parent activity. This requires less effort than changing resources. It is also better maintainability. Answer below overriding `Context` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.

Comment: there should be a simple setting that developers can use in android manifest to not follow the system text and display size setting.

Comment: Dp cant be used in jetpack compose for text units

Answer (score 71):

None of the previous answers worked for me, on Android 8.1 (API 27). Here's what worked: Add the following code to your activity:

Kotlin Code:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    
    val newOverride = Configuration(newBase?.resources?.configuration)
    newOverride.fontScale = 1.0f
    applyOverrideConfiguration(newOverride)

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
}
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

You don't need to change your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: This is the solution for Android API > N, Not tested on devices below N.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() or getAssets() has already been called

Comment: @Dr.DS is it API > N or API >= N ? For me, it's not working on N. Just wanted to confirm

Comment: @Dr.DS I have tested in below N device which working good

Comment: @diogenesgg working fine but activity is being recreated when I change font/zoom level while app is in background that's why I lost data in dialog  and other calculations, I'm also not able to call onconfigurationchanged() method from base activity.

Comment: @applyOverrideConfiguration was not found

Comment: Confirm it works on Android 12. But `super.attachBaseContext(newBase);` need to moved to last line of attachBaseContext()

Comment: it is working like a charm, this answer saved my time. thumbs up

Comment: This is working fine. I have used it in an Activity. Can we use it in BaseAactivity?

Comment: I'm using Capacitor v3 to build out my Android app and having the same issue. My MainActivity.java file only has 3 lines of code and I'm not very familiar with Java. How do I implement the above code in my project?

--MainActivity.java--
package com.domain.app;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}

Comment: For Java you can use `override.setToDefaults();` to make sure that the default setting for each device will be reset, rather than having t o worry about the different settings for each device.

Comment: I added this and got a problem with onConfigurationChange method. That wouldn't update my screen orientation on rotation. It seems adding this to activity prevent further updates on configuration.

Comment: @mmdrezabaqalpour I also had that problem and assigning the font scale directly to the newBase did the job. override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) { newBase?.resources?.configuration?.fontScale = 1.0f super.attachBaseContext(newBase) }

Answer (score 65):

I recently ran into this problem as well. Our UI didn't scale well on phones with limited screen dimensions and changing the entire UI on the off chance a user set's their Accessibility Options to "Huge" seemed silly.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786439/how-to-set-font-scale-in-my-own-android-application) on StackOverflow to be most helpful.

What I did was put the following code below in my BaseActivity (an Activity class that all my activities extend from)

```
public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration.fontScale > 1.30) {
        LogUtil.log(LogUtil.WARN, TAG, "fontScale=" + configuration.fontScale); //Custom Log class, you can use Log.w
        LogUtil.log(LogUtil.WARN, TAG, "font too big. scale down..."); //Custom Log class, you can use Log.w
        configuration.fontScale = 1.30f;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}
```

And called it right after my `super.onCreate()` like so

```
adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());
```

What this code does is identify if the user set their font scale in Accessibility Settings to something greater than 1.30f (1.30f is "Large" on The Note 5, but probably varies a bit from device-to-device). If the user set their font too large ("Extra Large", "Huge"...), we scale the application only to "Large".

This allows your app to scale to a user's preferences (to a degree) without distorting your UI. Hopefully this will help others. Good luck scaling!

**Other Tips**

If you want certain layouts to scale with your fonts (say...a `RelativeLayout` that you use as a backdrop against your fonts), you can set their width/height with sp instead of the classic dp. When a user changes their font size, the layout will change accordingly with the fonts in your application. Nice little trick.

Comment: Can I ask why your example is slightly different from the question you linked, regarding this line: `WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);`. I'm new to android and am trying to pick the 'best' answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tallboy good question. I've seen code get the window manager both ways (using the getSystemService call like I did and using getWindowManager() like the example I linked to). I just tested my code both ways and they both worked fine. I believe I read somewhere that getWindowManager returns a read-only Window Manager object and that may be a key difference between the two methods, but for this example it didn't matter.

Comment: This doesn't work on Nougat. Upto Marshmallow it works fine.

Comment: I've looked across the entire web for days, and this is the only solution that works with Capacitor! Thanks!

Comment: updateConfiguration method is deprecated!

Comment: This stopped working for me with Capacitor 3.

Answer (score 11):

That's how we do it.
In **Application** class override ***onConfigurationChanged()*** like this.
If you want different behavior for different activities - override ***onConfigurationChanged()*** in Activity.

*Don't forget to add manifest tag **android:configChanges="fontScale"** since you are hadnling this configuration change yourself.*

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // In some cases modifying newConfig leads to unexpected behavior,
    // so it's better to edit new instance.
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(newConfig);
    SystemUtils.adjustFontScale(getApplicationContext(), configuration);
}
```

In some helper class we have ***adjustFontScale()*** method.

```
public static void adjustFontScale(Context context, Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration.fontScale != 1) {
        configuration.fontScale = 1;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}
```

**WARNING!** That will totally ignore Accessibility Font Scale user settings and will prevent your App fonts scaling!

Comment: It does not work. The onConfigurationChanged is never triggered.

Comment: @zed you need to set android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" on the application or activity in the manifest

Comment: This solution is working on only tablet not smart devices.

Comment: it works on nexus 5-Android 6, i will check on other device.

Comment: Looking at a few source code implementations (in 5.1 and 10) for `updateConfiguration`, updating `scaledDensity` manually is not necessary. They do it for you.

Answer (score 6):

That's how you do it in 2018 (Xamarin.Android/C# - same approach in other languages):

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
...
    }

    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration(@base.Resources.Configuration);

        configuration.FontScale = 1f;
        var config =  Application.Context.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);

        base.AttachBaseContext(config);
    }
}
```

All you need is override *attachBaseContext* method of activity and update config there.

*getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration()* is deprecated though there're numerous examples with this method. If you use this approach besides the IDE warning you might find some parts of your app not scaled.

Answer (score 4):

There's another way to prevent app layout issue / font issue from the setting font size change. 
You can try

```
// ignore the font scale here
final Configuration newConfiguration = new Configuration(
    newBase.getResources().getConfiguration()
);

newConfiguration.fontScale = 1.0f;
applyOverrideConfiguration(newConfiguration);
```

where newBase is from attachBaseContext function. 
You need to override this callback in your Activity.

But, the side effect is that if you wanna use animation (objectanimator/valueanimator), then it will cause the weird behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it by changing `sp` to `dp` in .XML file. However, I also need to fix the text size of the **WebViews**.

Normally, to adjust the text size of the `WebView` the `setDefaultFontSize()` function is used. However, its default value unit is `sp`.

In my project, I used `setTextZoom(100)` to fix the text and icon size of the WebView.* (There are other methods in stackoverflow but almost all of them are **deprecated**)*

```java
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setTextZoom(100);
```

[For further details about setTextZoom()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setTextZoom(int))

Answer (score 3):

you can force to text size of your app using base activity Configuration, make all activities inherent base activity. 1.0f will force the app font size to normal ignoring system settings.

```
public  void adjustFontScale( Configuration configuration,float scale) {

configuration.fontScale = scale;
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);

}

@Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     adjustFontScale( getResources().getConfiguration(),1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried answers about disabling `fontScale` in whole application. It's working, but I come to answer it's a **terrible idea** for only one reason:

> You don't make your app better for visually impaired people.

Better way (I think) it's allow font scale but with restrictions only in some places, where you can't scale your text for it looks readable.

---

**Realization** (*10.02.22*)

After a day of thinking, I created **Kotlin** extension for `TextView` (also may use for `EditText` because it's a child):

```
fun TextView.removeFontScale() {
    val fontScale = resources.configuration.fontScale
    if (fontScale != 1f) {
        val scaledTextSize = textSize
        val newTextSize = scaledTextSize / fontScale / fontScale
        textSize = newTextSize
    }
}
```

Need divide `scaledTextSize` twice because after setting a new `textSize` for `TextView` font scale will happen.

---

**UPDATE / FIX** (*14.02.22*)

Previous solution doesn't work on real devices, only emulator (vice versa it overwise increasing text size). So, I found another way:

```
val scaledTextSize = textSize
val newTextSize = scaledTextSize / fontScale
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, newTextSize)
```

Here new `textSize` for `TextView` after setting will not be scaled on `fontScale` value.

---

**Use example:**

```
titleText.removeFontScale()
subtitleText.removeFontScale()
```

**Logs** of working, size in **1.3/1.5** scale become like in **1.0** scale:

- Old realization (*10.02.22*):

  ```
  fontScale: 1.0 | oldSize: 20    
  fontScale: 1.3 | oldSize: 26 | newSize: 20.0
  ```
- New realization (*14.02.22*):

  ```
  fontScale: 1.5 | oldSize: 83.0 | newSize: 55.333332 | textSize: 55.333332
  fontScale: 1.5 | oldSize: 58.0 | newSize: 38.666668 | textSize: 38.666668
  ```

---

*P.S. I notice that standard `Toolbar` didn't scale fonts and after that I understand that this practice is OK (disable scaling where it's really need).*

Comment: Regarding "You don't make your app better for visually impaired people.", It's sometimes the opposite. Android support for xsmall and xbig font sizes is almost null and most views will simply cut the text to some degree. Autoshrink components, miltiline, and width & height calculations don't work properly

Sometimes it will become worse for the user than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think usage of `dp` is the best way, but in some case you may want to use a font style. However, the style is using `sp`, you can convert `sp` to `dp` by:

```
fun TextView.getSizeInSp() = textSize / context.resources.displayMetrics.scaleDensity

fun TextView.convertToDpSize() = setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getSizeInSp())
```

So, you can use the `sp` value from style without dynamic font size, and no need to hardcode the font size

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest best answer is from the user below "If you have a working app, switching all sp values to dp values is error prone and requires more time to do so. Then if chose to switch back to support it again, you need to revert all these changes. It just makes more sense to override fontScale in a parent activity. This requires less effort than changing resources. It is also better maintainability. Answer below overriding Context is the way to go. –
parohy"
Apr 7, 2021 at 5:18

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer before, but this wouldn't update screen orientation on rotation.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

I modify some code, this will update screen orientation on rotation.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    Configuration old = newBase.getResources().getConfiguration();
    
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    newBase = newBase.createConfigurationContext(override);
    
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

Comment: I also had the same problem with rotation when using applyOverrideConfiguration, in my case assigning the font scale directly to the newBase did the job.

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        newBase?.resources?.configuration?.fontScale = 1.0f
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the fontScale directly to the 'newBase' context in the attachBaseContext method of the activity did the job for me

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {

    //Ignore font size changed in device settings and set the default
    newBase?.resources?.configuration?.fontScale = 1.0f

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 14 or above, reset `DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity` will not work since `fontScaleConverter` was introduced to handle font scale:
[image]

Override `getResources()` method in activity as below:

```
override fun getResources(): Resources {
    val resources = super.getResources()
    resources.updateConfiguration(
        Configuration(resources.configuration).apply {
            fontScale = 1.0f
        },
        resources.displayMetrics
    )
    return resources
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing **sp** to **dp** will  definitely work but it'll be very long process to change all files or many places like drawable layout etc if you have alredy created BaseActvity for whole you should use following code it may be you'll not able to generate this method so you can just copy paste inside your base activity

for Kotlin

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

for java

```
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    Configuration old = newBase.getResources().getConfiguration();
    
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    newBase = newBase.createConfigurationContext(override);
    
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```