# Avoid changing font scale of app when changed from system settings on Android 7.0

Tags: android, font-size, android-settings

I am working on **LGE Nexus 5x** which runs on **Android 7.0** & I want to restrict any system font changes to change my application font size.

I have already gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application), and also
I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832216/4774696) which works perfectly upto Marshmallow. But doesn't work on Nougat.

In my Application class I have added these lines;

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    adjustFontScale(new Configuration(newConfig));
}


public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration != null && configuration.fontScale != 1.0) {
        configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.0;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}
```

In manifest, under `application tag` I have declared;

```
android:configChanges="fontScale"
```

But that doesn't work on Nougat devices even though `onConfigurationChanged` is called and executed without any exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve it by overriding `onConfigurationChanged` in Activity instead of Application class & changing `getBaseContext()` to

```
this.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```