# React-Native accessibility limit fontSize scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, react-native-ios

do you know how to natively limit the fontSize multiplier that comes with accessibility on iOS. I saw this gist : https://gist.github.com/Jpoliachik/ed5cb38b480bc544427ce0db529786bf
But it seems outdated and I'm not good enough in Obj-C to fix it.

Answer (score 22):

**Solution for React Native `=< 0.58`**

iOS uses `AccessibilityManager` fro that (which is not available for Android)
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/IntegrationTests/AccessibilityManagerTest.js

Android requires a native (Java) solution, 
[how to prevent system font-size changing effects to android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application/32832216#32832216)

**For React Native >= 0.59**

`Text` and `TextInput` component have a `maxFontSizeMultiplier` prop. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/text#maxfontsizemultiplier

With it, the app will be able to have a *cross-platform* solution to set font scale capping from JS

In your App.js:

```
Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.maxFontSizeMultiplier = 1.3;

TextInput.defaultProps = {};
TextInput.defaultProps.maxFontSizeMultiplier = 1.3;
```