# How to change menu drawer-view items text size from "sp" to "dp"

Tags: android, text

So as I researched the only way to prevent your android app to accept system current set fonts is to use "dp" instead of "sp" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application). So it did worked but not really. Since menu layout for drawer-view is a little different from normal layouts and there is not even attribute textSize i do not really know how to do that.
Here is the code

**Drawer-view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/activities"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_date_range_blue_24dp"
            android:title="@string/Start" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/newReview"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_blue_24dp"
            android:title="@string/newReview" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/myReviews"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_date_range_blue_24dp"
            android:title="@string/myReviews" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_blue_24dp"
            android:title="@string/profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_blue_24dp"
            android:title="@string/messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_half_green_24dp"
            android:title="@string/feedback" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/exit_group">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_blue_24dp"
            android:title="Изход">

        </item>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/application">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:title="@string/terms" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/rights">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:title="@string/rights" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

As you can see drawer-view font-size is much bigger than the normal-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this code inside the styles.xml

  <style name="menu_text_style" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#0D2142</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

    </style>
```

and add on navigationView 
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/menu_text_style"