# How to block android:textSize

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, text-size

I have an hybrid app and if users change the font size with settings of mobile, I have some problem with the layout.
So, I would like that the font-size doesn't change with settings. 
I have searched a lot and I have tried to do this:
1. **In res > values > strings.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">22dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

2. **In AndroidManifest.xml**

   ```
   <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.app.myapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
           <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
               <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
       </application>
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
   </manifest>
   ```

But this doesn't work and I don't understand why.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: the style things does not belong to string.xml it belong to styles.xml

Comment: is it a file that I have to create? Or it already exists and I have to modify it?

Comment: can you post your xml please

Comment: which xml are you referring to? config.xml?

Comment: res > values > styles.xml

Comment: I don't have that file. I have only res > values > strings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

try with `sp`.

```
<item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
```

from [prevent system font size changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546805/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-android-application)

Comment: Yes, I already tried but I have the same result. So, it doesn't work.