# Accessibility font size and UI

Tags: android, user-interface, fonts

So I have probably uncommon situation, I change Font size in settings under accessibility to huge and it changes font size through all apps. In my app it just ruins all UI. So my questions are:

- Can I prevent resizing in my app?
- Can I somehow adapt UI that it wouldn't push things around when fonts increasing in size?
- How professionals deals with this situation?

Comment: **(1)** We cannot stop the user from changing the device font size, but we can use dp for dimensions to avoid unwanted UI distortion. You can refer: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP. **(2)** I found this question on StackOverflow and found it helpful, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786439/how-to-set-font-scale-in-my-own-android-application. **(3)** Professional developers also follow these concepts and build great apps!

Answer (score 1):

In your app do not use sp for your font sizes in order your app's font sizes to be the same, after changing font sizes from your phone settings.
I think this answer also could help you: [What is the difference between “px”, “dip”, “dp” and “sp”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Hope I answered your question ;).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prevent resizing in app. Just add the below code under your activity tag in your Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="fontScale"
```

For example :

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"    
  android:configChanges="fontScale"
  ....
  ..../>
```